# How does one generate a formula(s) for an artificial satellite's location at time t given a set of known locations at discrete times?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, mathematics, communication-satellite, coordinates

Given a set of spatio-temporal points in space {(Lat_1, Lon_1, Alt_1, Time_1), ... (Lat_n, Lon_n, Alt_n, Time_n)}, I need a function (i.e. a formula) that takes these points (or subset of points) as input and outputs something like (Lat(t), Lon(t), Alt(t)). I.e.:

f(S; t) = (Lat(t), Lon(t), Alt(t)) where S = {(Lat_1, Lon_1, Alt_1, Time_1), ... (Lat_n, Lon_n, Alt_n, Time_n)} or a subset of this set, and t is a time period before, after or in between Time_1 and Time_n.

The purpose of this is to be able to calculate (or at least estimate) where artificial satellites (LEO, MEO, and HEO) are at specific points in time given a set of discrete observations. We can assume there will be more than 3 observations. I'm not sure if the equations for HEOs is more complex due to their shape. If this is a rookie question I apologize as this is admittingly outside of my domain. I am building a python program for this, which is why a function/formula would be nice.

Comment: The problem you are describing is *orbit determination*.  This is **very** difficult to do well.  Writing your own is theoretically possible, but almost certainly a bad idea, because of the very many mistakes one might make in trying to reproduce the work of large numbers of experts with paying customers who fund bug fixes.  If you are a student, you may be able to get some decent stuff free, but the general price for these things starts at 30,000 USD and goes up from there.  Working by yourself for a few months is not remotely sufficient to replace any existing tool's capabilities.

Comment: What if the use-case tolerates a pretty wide margin of error? for example +/= 3 degrees lat/lon. The purpose of this is to determine which non-geo communication-satellites an antenna is pointed at. I assume that these satellites are sparse enough that given the country/affiliation of the ground station and the aziumuth/elevation there can be a generous error tolerance that still narrows it down to a few satellites. If I am wrong I apologize. Perhaps I should also rephrase the question.

Comment: @Imp  you can get TLE data from a variety of sources. This is tracked and updated, and there are a variety of open source software packages that will let you move back and forth in time to tell you the position for that application. If you know the name of the satellite then it can be even easier as there are sites that will tell you what times they are visible for your location.  https://celestrak.com/ is a good place to start. But there other resources out there too. Orbital element data degrades over time, but for what you are doing, it should be good enough.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem But of course that's of limited use for real satellites affected by drag, the actual gravitational field of Earth, and perturbations due to other celestial bodies. FWIW, Horizons can propagate TLEs. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/